# Eliminar espacio al leer un texto en python

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas al leer un archivo, es un vector con una serie de numeros, deseo operar con ese dato, pero al momento de leerlo me agrega un "\n" salto de linea que no está en mi archivo de texto, estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
infile=open('uncarb.txt')
x=infile.read()
print(x)
infile.close
```

[image: DEspues de la serie de numeros me imprime un salto de linea no deseado]

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: Si utilizas python 3.x, la sintaxis es `print(x, end="")`, para python 2 es, como bien dices, `,` puedes consultar más de ello en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end) pregunta

Answer (score 1):

No está claro si, como dices en la pregunta, te añade un salto de línea *al leer* del fichero, o si, como te han respondido otros usuarios, el salto de línea se produce *al imprimir* lo que has leido.

Ya que nadie te ha respondido aún cómo resolverlo si fuera el primer caso (*al leer*), añado yo esta respuesta. La captura de pantalla que incluyes tampoco ayuda mucho ya que no se ve claramente dónde estaría ese retorno de carro extra que mencionas.

El método `.rstrip()` de las cadenas sirve para eliminar espacios o retornos de carro que la cadena pueda contener al final. También tienes `.lstrip()` para eliminar los que pueda contener al principio y `.strip()` para ambos lados a la vez. Por tanto:

```
with open('uncarb.txt') as infile:
    x=infile.read().strip()
print(x)
```

Y ya de paso, aunque esto no lo preguntabas, parece que lo que lees del fichero es una cadena que contiene la representación ASCII de una lista (quizás JSON). Ya que dices que luego vas a procesar esos datos, necesitarás convertirla a una lista de números python. En este caso puedes hacer:

```
lista = eval(x)
```

O, si prefieres no correr riesgos de seguridad (no confías en que el contenido del fichero que estás leyendo pueda contener código python peligroso que se ejecutaría como parte del `eval()`), puedes eliminar los corchetes que delimitan la lista y después separarla por las comas, así:

```
x = x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
lista = [ int(n) for n in x.split(",") ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
infile=open('uncarb.txt')
x=infile.read()
print(x),
infile.close
```

Se le tiene que agregar una , al final de print para evitar el salto de linea

Answer (score 0):

El `print` de `Python` agrega un salto de linea: `\n`. Una buena solución es usar otra herramienta que no agregué. Además te aconsejo usar `with` que es un `context-manager` que automáticamente se encarga de cerrar el archivo cuando salis del bloque de código (de esta manera obvias el `close`)

```
import sys

with open("uncarb.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```